# How to use modularity in this program by using functions

Tags: c, pointers

How to rewrite this program by using various functions.
Program to find the sum and difference of two dynamic matrices. 
It uses pointer to pointer instead of two dimensional matrix for dynamic size of the matrix

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{   int i, n, j, **a, **b, **c, **d;
    printf("Input the size of matrix [if n x n, input n]: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nInput matrix A\n");
    a=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   *(a+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if(!*a)
        {   printf("\nInsufficient memory");
            exit(0);
        }
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {   
            printf("Enter [%d][%d] element: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", (*(a+i)+j));
            printf("%d", *(*(a+i)+j));
        }
    }
    printf("\nInput matrix B\n");
    b=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   *(b+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if(!*b)
        {   printf("\nInsufficient memory");
            exit(0);
        }
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {   
            printf("Enter [%d][%d] element: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", (*(b+i)+j));
            printf("%d", *(*(b+i)+j));
        }
    }
    c=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    d=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   *(c+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        *(d+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if(!(*c&&*d))
        {   printf("Insufficient memory");
            exit(0);
        }
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {   *(*(c+i)+j)=(*(*(a+i)+j))+(*(*(b+i)+j));
            *(*(d+i)+j)=(*(*(a+i)+j))-(*(*(b+i)+j));
            printf("\nA[%d][%d]= %d   B[%d][%d]= %d \t Sum= %d \t Diff= %d", i, j, *(*(a+i)+j),     i, j, *(*(b+i)+j), *(*(c+i)+j), *(*(d+i)+j));
        }
    }
    free(c);
    free(d);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

I have written this code but, it is not working correctly

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void input(int n, int **a);
void operation(int n, int **a, int **b);
int main()
{   int i, n, j, **a, **b, **c, **d;
    printf("Input the size of matrix [if n x n, input n]: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nInput matrix A\n");
    input(n, a);
    printf("\nInput matrix B\n");
    input(n, b);
    operation(n, a, b);
    free(c);
    free(d);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
void input(int n, int **a)
{   int i, j;
    a=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   *(a+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if(!*a)
        {   printf("\nInsufficient memory");
            exit(0);
        }
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {   
            printf("Enter [%d][%d] element: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", (*(a+i)+j));
            printf("%d", *(*(a+i)+j));
        }
    }
}
void operation(int n, int**a, int**b)
{   int i, j, **c, **d;
    a=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    b=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    c=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    d=(int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   *(a+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        *(b+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        *(c+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        *(d+i)=(int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if(!(*a&&*b&&*c&&*d))
        {   printf("Insufficient memory");
            exit(0);
        }
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {   *(*(c+i)+j)=(*(*(a+i)+j))+(*(*(b+i)+j));
            *(*(d+i)+j)=(*(*(a+i)+j))-(*(*(b+i)+j));
            printf("\nA[%d][%d]= %d   B[%d][%d]= %d \t Sum= %d \t Diff= %d", i, j, *(*(a+i)+j), i, j, *(*(b+i)+j), *(*(c+i)+j), *(*(d+i)+j));
        }
    }
    free(c);
    free(d);
}
```

Comment: `not working correctly`..please explain.

Comment: in operation function when i print A[][], B[][], sum and difference all have value 0

Comment: what else would you expect? you're allocating memory freshly, right?

Comment: `void input(int n, int **a)` --> `void input(int n, int ***a)` and call `input(n, &a)` or `int **input(int n)`

Comment: Why do you overwrite `a` and `b` in `operation`? You lose any values those arrays may have had.

Comment: when i did not allocate memory again, it gives a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **new_imat(int n);
void drop_imat(int n, int **mat);
void input(int n, int **mat);
void operation(int n, int **mat_a, int **mat_b);

int main(){
    int i, j, n;
    int **a, **b;
    printf("Input the size of matrix [if n x n, input n]: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = new_imat(n);
    b = new_imat(n);
    printf("\nInput matrix A\n");
    input(n, a);
    printf("\nInput matrix B\n");
    input(n, b);
    operation(n, a, b);
    drop_imat(n, a);
    drop_imat(n, b);
    return 0;
}

typedef enum opt {
    NONINIT, INIT
} OPT;

void *alloc_with_err(size_t size, size_t type_size, OPT opt){
    void *ret = opt ? calloc(size, type_size) : malloc(size*type_size);
    if(!ret){
        fprintf(stderr, "\nInsufficient memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return ret;
}

int **new_imat(int n){
    int r, **mat;
    mat = alloc_with_err(n, sizeof(int*), NONINIT);
    for(r = 0; r < n; ++r){
        mat[r] = alloc_with_err(n, sizeof(int), INIT);
    }
    return mat;
}
void drop_imat(int n, int **mat){
    int r;
    for(r = 0; r < n; ++r)
        free(mat[r]);
    free(mat);
}

void input(int n, int **mat){
   int r, c;
    for(r=0; r<n; r++){
        for(c=0; c<n; c++){
            printf("Enter [%d][%d] element: ", r, c);
            scanf("%d", (*(mat+r)+c));
        }
    }
}
void print(int n, int **mat){
   int r, c;
    for(r=0; r<n; r++){
        for(c=0; c<n; c++){
            printf("%d ", mat[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void operation(int n, int **a, int **b){
    int r, c;
    int **sum=new_imat(n);
    int **dif=new_imat(n);
    for(r=0; r < n; r++){
        for(c=0; c < n; c++){
           sum[r][c] = a[r][c] + b[r][c];
           dif[r][c] = a[r][c] - b[r][c];
        }
    }
    printf("A:\n");print(n, a);
    printf("B:\n");print(n, b);
    printf("Sum:\n"); print(n, sum);
    printf("Diff:\n");print(n, dif);
    drop_imat(n, sum);
    drop_imat(n, dif);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

`int **a` is local to `input` function. So when you return from the function, value of local `a` is lost, and value of `a` in `main` will remain garbage. You must pass *address of variable holding the matrix* to make assigment stick. In other words the parameter should be `int ***a`.

**Solution:**

But you don't really need that parameter at all. You could just return the array:

```
int** input(int n)
{   
    int i, j;
    int ** a = calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {   
        a[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if(!a[i])

        ...

     return a;
}
```

**Other problems:**

- Don't reallocate `a` and `b` in `operation`.
- [You should not cast return value of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694733).
- Use array syntax when possible, it is much cleaner. `*(*(a+i)+j)` -> `a[i][j]`
- Always check return value of `scanf`. It is an I/O operation, and it can fail.